# how is it possible to hack an iphone app for its database within?

Tags: iphone

hi everyone im curious to find out if it is possible for an end user to hack an iphone application and access the database files inside?  And if so,  how is it possible ?

Comment: Do you mean files that are created by the app or files that come bundled with the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's possible if the iphone is jailbroken. in this case you have root access to it.

Comment: You can also get the application's files from the iPhone backup. No jailbreak required.

Comment: Hi Thilo and Heximal thanksfor the tip but what is the iPhone backup ?

Comment: i don't know the details, but think, Thilo talks about backups that are created while iTunes synchrinization process. They must be somewhere on the hard disk of PC.